# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me devuelva los valores de una lista?

Tags: lista, kotlin

Tengo el siguiente problema, en una lista de ejemplo:

```
list = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

necesito que me devuelva los valores "c,d,e".

```
//no vale esto
for (i in lis){
  if (i==c || i==d || i==e) println(i)
}
```

necesito que recorra la lista y me saque entre toda la lista estos dichos valores sin tener que recurrir a estos if, pensé en este caso hipotético pero no se implementarlo

```
var inicio = 0
var final = 0
for (i in list){
  //teniendo en cuenta un inicio y un final dentro de la lista 
}
```

Comment: Hola Juan David, si no te vale lo que has puesto... ¿Cuál es la condición de que salgan esos valores? ¿Que sean consonantes? ¿Que estén en índice impar? Porque la única manera que se me ocurre es con la comparación.

Comment: Hola Juan David, si necesitas sacar el valor si o si deberás utilizar un _if_ para hacer la comparación de los elementos y o posiciones.
La otra opción puedes ser con un when, 
when (list){
}